# Hiding dexterity field according user property

Tags: plone, dexterity

While adding dexterity object, I have two fields in which we like to display only one field according to user property which is saved in members data.

Schema definition is somewhat like:

```
class IMyApplication(form.schema):
      fieldA = schema.textline(...)
      fieldB = schema.textline(...)
```

I would like to show one fields out of these two field to user according to their user property.

Many thanks in advance for guide/link/advise .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First please consider the example for a custom add/edit form in the [DX-docu](http://developer.plone.org/content/dexterity.html)

Then you are able to hide a field in the updateWidgets method of the form.

Example Code (not tested):

```python
from plone.dexterity.browser.add import DefaultAddForm
from z3c.form import interfaces


class AddForm(DefaultAddForm):

    def updateWidgets(self):
        super(AddForm, self).updateWidgets()

        if my_condition:
            self.widgets['myfield'].mode = interfaces.HIDDEN_MODE
```

Since you have to do the same in the `add` and `edit` form, you could create a mixin class with your customization.